# celery 2 instances with different code sources

Tags: python, django, celery

I have two kinds of worker:

1. A first kind linked to django making db polling
2. A second kind without any interaction with django.

I use `rabbitMQ` as broker and launch in a first time the two kinds of worker on the same server.

I would like to separate the code between kind 1 and kind 2 to be able to launch the workers in a separated server in the future. I want to avoid django code in the server running the second kind of worker.

On django worker side I defined them like this:

```
@shared_task(name='task_polling')
def task_polling():
    send_task('do_work', [], {'_serialized_task': serialized_task})

@shared_task(name='save_shell_task')
def save_shell_task(_result):
    pass
```

And the following celery configuration:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
from datetime import timedelta
from celery import Celery


# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'ussd_auto.settings.local')


app = Celery(include=[
    'app_task_management.tasks',
])

app.conf.update(
    CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT=True,
    CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=['json'],
    CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER='json',
    CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE={
        'periodic_task': {
            'task': 'task_polling',
            'schedule': timedelta(seconds=1),
        },
    },
)
```

I launch these workers with the following command:

```
celery -A my_app worker -B -l info
```

On the startup screen the tasks are well registered:

```
 -------------- celery@mbp-de-julio.home v3.1.12 (Cipater)
---- **** -----
--- * ***  * -- Darwin-13.1.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
-- * - **** ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         __main__:0x102341390
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ----
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . save_shell_task
  . task_polling
```

On the other side I defined the tasks and celery configuration like that:

```
from celery import Celery
from celery import shared_task
from celery.execute import send_task

from task_workers import task_workers

app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

@shared_task(name='do_work')
def do_work(_serialized_task):
    result = task_workers.Worker().do(_task=_serialized_task)
    send_task('save_shell_task', [], {'_result':result})
```

I launch this worker with this command:

```
    celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
```

The start screen show that the task is well registered:

```
 -------------- celery@mbp-de-julio.home v3.1.12 (Cipater)
---- **** -----
--- * ***  * -- Darwin-13.1.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
-- * - **** ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         tasks:0x101833450
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ----
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . do_work
```

But it seems that the two instances of celery don't know how to communicate:

```
[2014-07-09 22:21:52,184: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type u'task_polling'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you are using relative imports?
Please see http://bit.ly/gLye1c for more information.

The full contents of the message body was:
[...]
KeyError: u'task_polling'
```

How can I configure celery on both side to fix the communication issue?

**Update 10/07**

When I launch the beat with the polling task alone, the polling is working but when I launch the celery with the other workers, this celery receive the message for the polling and says that he doesn't know this task. Maybe I have to attribute distinct queue for the tasks?

I defined the queues.

On worker kind 2 side, celeryconfig.py file:

```
CELERY_ROUTES = {
    'do_work': {
        'queue': 'task_workers_queue'
    },
    'task_polling': {
        'queue': 'db_workers_queue'
    },
    'save_shell_task': {
        'queue': 'db_workers_queue'
    },
}
```

On db worker kind 1 side:

```
app.conf.update(
    CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT=True,
    CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=['json'],
    CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER='json',
    CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE={
        'periodic_task': {
            'task': 'task_polling',
            'schedule': timedelta(seconds=1),
        },
    },
    CELERY_ROUTES={
        'task_polling': {
            'queue': 'db_workers_queue'
        },
        'save_shell_task': {
            'queue': 'db_workers_queue'
        },
        'do_work': {
            'queue': 'task_workers_queue'
        }
    },
)
```

I launch the celeries like this:

```
$ celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info -Q task_workers_queue
$ celery -A ussd_auto worker -B -l info -Q db_workers_queue
```

Now the periodic task `db_polling` is well called by beat.
This tasks succeed in sending the job to `do_work` task.
But `do_work` task failed to send the result to the task `save_shell_task`.
No error but nothing append.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first try you have two workers configured on the same broker but with different registered tasks.
In the first scenario the 2 workers will receive tasks in round robin from the broker that why the first error:

```
Received unregistered task of type u'task_polling'.
```

It's obvious and expected for the second worker that does not have this task registered, he actually don't know the source code.

In your update you are logically thinking to create dedicated queue per worker, this is surely a proper solution to avoid that a worker takes a task it shouldn't get from the broker.
You are doing only one mistake, celery send_task method will not care about the routing, this is way is just an api to send and AMQP message to the broker, routing is taken in account when scheduling the task via task class.
To make it work you need to specify the queue in the send task method in this way:

```
send_task('save_shell_task', [], kwargs={'_result':result, queue=queue})
```

More on the topic:

[Can I call a task by name ?](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-call-a-task-by-name)

[send_task source](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/9e3ba44b979bb21f5db26c201a4362378cf769b5/celery/app/base.py#L353)

Hope this helps